# how to filter sum types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

for example

```
data CampingStuff = Apple String Int 
                  | Banana String Int
                  | Pineapple String Int
                  | Table String Int
                  | Chairs String Int
```

I want to have a query function

```
pickStuff :: [CampingStuff] ->  ??? -> [CampingStuff]
```

the `???` I want to pass `Apple` then the `pickStuff` is going to filter out all stuffs like

```
Apple "Jane" 3
Apple "Jack" 5
Apple "Lucy" 6
```

something I can think of is like

```
pickStuffs stuffs dummyStuff
  = filter 
      (\x ->
        (x == dummyStuff)
      stuffs

pickStuffs stuffs (Apple "" 0)

instance Eq CampingStuff where
  compare (Apple name1 number1) (Apple name2 number2)
     = True
```

the drawback of it is :

- passing extra parameters to dummy value is not elegant and is not making any sense `"" 0`
- it has to implement all the value constructor in Eq type class ( Apple, Table , Chair)
- it is not scalable as in the future I would like to filter out all the apples from Janes

  - like this `(Apple "Jane" _)`

Thank you for reading this and appreciate any help how to filter on this `[CampingStuff]` by `Data Constructor` like `Apple/Table` ?

Comment: The repetition of `String Int` in every alternative doesn't look healthy to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that unsaturated constructors can't really be compared by value. The only things you can do with them are invoke them or pattern match on them. So if you want a function that tests for Apple, it'll have to be totally different from a function that tests for Banana - they can't share any code, because they have to compare against a different set of patterns.

This is all much easier if you refactor your type to remove the obvious duplication, leaving you with saturated value constructors. The generated Eq instance is all you'll need for comparing types:

```
data StuffType = Apple | Banana | Pineapple | Table | Chairs deriving Eq
data CampingStuff = Stuff { stuffType :: StuffType
                          , owner :: String
                          , quantity :: Int
                          }
```

Then you can easily write a function of type `CampingStuff -> Bool` by composing a couple functions.

```
hasType :: StuffType -> CampingStuff -> Bool
hasType t s = stuffType s == t
```

and use that to filter a list:

```
pickStuff :: StuffType -> [CampingStuff] -> [CampingStuff]
pickStuff = filter . hasType
```

---

In the comments, you ask: What if my constructors weren't all uniform, so I couldn't extract everything out to a product type with an enum in it?

I argue that, in such a case, you won't be happy with the result of a `pickStuff` function no matter how it's implemented. Let's imagine a simpler type:

```
data Color = Red | Green
data Light = Off | On Color
```

Now, you might wish to filter a `[Light]` such that it includes only lights that are On, regardless of their color. Fine, we can implement that. We won't even worry about generalizing, because the type is so small:

```
ons :: [Light] -> [Light]
ons = filter on
  where on Off = False
        on (On _) = True
```

Now you have `lights :: [Light]`, and you can get `onLights = ons lights :: [Light]`. Amazing. What will you do with `onLights` next? Perhaps you want to count how many of each color there are:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

colorCounts :: [Light] -> M.Map Color Int
colorCounts = M.fromListWith (+) . map getColor
  where getColor (On c) = (c, 1)
```

`colorCounts` has a problem: it assumes all the lights are On, but there's no guarantee of that in the type system. So you can accidentally call `colorCounts ls` instead of `colorCounts (ons ls)`, and it will compile, but give you an error at runtime.

Better would be to just do your pattern matching at the point when you'll know what to do with the results. Here, that's inside of `colorCounts`: just add a case for `Off`, and use `mapMaybe` instead of `map` so you have a chance to throw away values you don't like:

```
colorCounts' :: [Light] -> M.Map Color Int
colorCounts' = M.fromListWith (+) . mapMabye getColor
  where getColor (On c) = Just (c, 1)
        getColor Off = Nothing
```

The same arguments all hold for more complicated types: don't pattern match on a value until you're ready to handle *all* the information you might find.

Of course, one way to handle such information is to put it into a new type that contains only the information you want. So you could very well write a function

```
colorsOfOnLights :: [Light] -> [Color]
colorsOfOnLights = mapMaybe go
  where go Off = Nothing
        go (On c) = Just c
```

This way, you can't possibly mix up the input of the "filter" function with the output: the output is clearly divorced from the original `Light` type, and its values can only have come from the `On` lights. You can do the same thing for your CampingStuff type by extracting a new product type for each of the constructors:

```
data CampingStuff = Apple AppleData
                  | Banana BananaData
                  -- ...

data AppleData = AppleData String Int Bool
data BananaData = BananaData String Int
-- ...

asApple :: CampingStuff -> Maybe AppleData
asApple (Apple ad) = Just ad
asApple _ = Nothing

apples :: [CampingStuff] -> [AppleData]
apples = mapMaybe asApple
```

You'll need separate functions for `asApple` and for `asBanana` and so on. This seems cumbersome, and I don't exactly disagree, but in practice people don't really need large numbers of functions like this. It's usually better to do as I described before: delay the pattern match until you know what to do with the results.

Comment: what if   `Apple` has extra field like "Apple String Int Bool" ,Bool implied `organic or not` ?
and other `Table` has extra field like size ? "Table String Int Int " ..Then the `CampingStuff` may not the best to cover all the cases ?

Answer (score 2):

For the function you want to have, you could create functions such as

```hs
isApple :: CampingStuff -> Bool
isApple Apple{} = True
isApple _ = False
```

and then use `filter isApple`. When you want to filter by Jane, you add another 5 functions for each type, like `isAppleFrom :: String -> CampingStuff -> Bool` and do `filter (isAppleFrom "Jane")`.

Another approach is the following:

```
data StuffType = AppleT | BananaT | PineappleT | TableT | ChairsT deriving Eq
data Query = ByStuff StuffType | ByName String deriving Eq

pickStuff :: [CampingStuff] -> [Query] -> [CampingStuff]
pickStuff xs qs = filter cond xs
  where
    cond :: CampingStuff -> Bool
    cond x = all (\q -> case (q, x) of
      (ByStuff AppleT, Apple{}) -> True
      ...other pairs...
      (ByName name1, Apple name2 _) -> name1 == name2
      ...
      _ -> False) qs
```

That is, separate querying from the data types. The above is an example and may be written better.